Can DecRef be optimized with refcount.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1?
IncRef:
refcount.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)

DecRef:
if (refcount.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1 ||
    refcount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  delete this;
}


Is it safe to compare the refcount to 1, and immediately delete the object without an actual release operation? The reasoning is that the only time the refcount can be 1 is if the current thread has the only reference.

Could you show full code you want to do? Because when the count is 1, this code already deletes the object without fetch_sub/release - the OR is short-circuting, so if refcount == 1, the second condition is not evaluated, and no decrement/release is performed.

I'm not sure if delete this is ever safe; I know this isn't allowed to be null.  But you could rework this to be not a member function so it's ptr->refcount and delete ptr.
I think this has a problem if another thread can create another reference with IncRef while you're in the middle of a DecRef.  If you always did refcount--, their fetch_add would see the old value as 0 and know that another thread has already or is about to delete the object and they were too late in trying to get a reference.
Without that, they have no way to distinguish that case from simply being the second reference.
But if that's impossible, e.g. because new references are created by an owner and then given to another thread, yes I think this is safe.
The acquire fence is necessary in case another thread just wrote to the object and did a DecRef, to make sure the stuff they did to the object's members happens-before the delete.  And yes, using an acquire fence means the load can be relaxed instead of acquire and the RMW can be just release not acq_rel.  On some ISA (like AArch64) it might be more efficient to use acquire and acq_rel operations and avoid a separate fence.

You're optimizing for the last-reference case by avoiding an RMW there, at the cost of making other calls slower.  That might or might not be good, depending on your use-case.
A couple extra instructions to load+branch before you RMW+branch, and that's another branch that needs to be predicted correctly.
Potentially you get the cache line into MESI Shared state with the read-only access, but then the RMW also misses in cache and has to do a read-for-ownership (RFO) to get it into MESI Exclusive/Modified state, so you have two off-core communications, hopefully pipelined with each other if the ==1 branch predicts correctly.  (Other than that, a load right before an RMW is nothing to worry about on typical CPUs.)

A follow up question. Internet states that refcount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) is safe to use in DecRef - but how can it be safe. Does memory_order_release guarantee that the fetch_sub sees an updated value of the refcount in case another thread recently decreased it?

@Luddes: It's an atomic RMW, so the value it stores is in the modification-order directly after the value it loads.  [atomics.order] p10.  That's what guarantees that multiple threads running fetch_sub(1, relaxed) 100 times will do a total of 100 decrements, (with each one seeing a different return value if there were no modifications).  Atomic RMWs on the same object from different threads are serialized into the order in which they got MESI ownership of the cache line.

@PeterCordes yes, delete this is safe (if used correctly) and actually quite common.

@PeterCordes of course, thanks.
